# Updating a UITableViewCell from a view model with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, mvvm, uitableview, viewmodel, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to code with **ReactiveCocoa** and the **MVVM** pattern and I am trying to setup a custom `UITableViewCel`l to update its labels when the according `viewModel` is getting a new model object.

The unit tests are passing so I know the view model itself is working so far. But I do not get the `UILabel`s to update their attributed text.

Here is my code for the `UITableViewCellModel`:

```
@interface GYMWorkoutTableViewCellModel : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSAttributedString *workoutName;
@property(nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSAttributedString *numberOfExercises;
@property(nonatomic, strong) GYMWorkout *workout;
@end

@implementation GYMWorkoutTableViewCellModel
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    RACSignal *newWorkoutSignal = [RACObserve(self, workout) ignore:nil];

    RAC(self, workoutName) = [newWorkoutSignal map:^id(GYMWorkout *workout1) {
        return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:workout1.name];
    }];

    RAC(self, numberOfExercises) = [newWorkoutSignal map:^id(GYMWorkout *workout2) {
        NSString *numberOfExercisesString = [@([workout2.exercises count]) stringValue];
        return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:numberOfExercisesString];
    }];

    return self;
}

@end
```

And here is the code for the cell itself:

```
@interface GYMWorkoutTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *workoutNameLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *numberOfExercisesLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) GYMWorkoutTableViewCellModel *viewModel;
@end

@implementation GYMWorkoutTableViewCell

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.viewModel = [GYMWorkoutTableViewCellModel new];

    RAC(self.workoutNameLabel, attributedText) = RACObserve(self, viewModel.workoutName);
    RAC(self.numberOfExercisesLabel, attributedText) = RACObserve(self, viewModel.numberOfExercises);

    return self;
}
@end
```

I am setting the workout property in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of the according view controller like this:

```
GYMWorkoutTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WorkoutCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
GYMWorkout *workout = [self.viewModel workoutAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.viewModel.workout = workout;
return cell;
```

Can anyone give me hints why the `RAC()` bindings in the `GymWorkoutTableViewCell` do not update the `UILabel`s?

### Edit

When I change the code in the `initWithCoder:` method to

```
[RACObserve(self, viewModel.workout) subscribeNext:^(GYMWorkout *gymWorkout) {
        self.workoutNameLabel.text = gymWorkout.name;
}];
```

the text of the `UILabel`s is changed. But this defeats the need for the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - I figured it out. The labels where all nil in initWithCoder: - so I had to postpone the RAC() binding until the everything is loaded from the nib.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    RAC(self.workoutNameLabel, text) = RACObserve(self, viewModel.workoutName);
    RAC(self.numberOfExercisesLabel, text) = RACObserve(self, viewModel.numberOfExercises);
}
```

And now the labels get updated :).

Comment: Yes it does because the when the workout property is set during cellForRowAtIndexPath: it triggers a signal that ultimately sets the label text.